# how to escape file path in bash script variable

Tags: string, bash, escaping, backslash, slash

I would like to escape a file path that is stored in a variable in a bash script.
I read several threads about escaping back ticks or but it seems not working as it should:

I have this variable:
The variables value is entered during the bash script execution as user parameter

```
CONFIG="/home/teams/blabla/blabla.yaml"
```

I would need to change this to: `\/home\/teams\/blabla\/blabla.yaml`

How can I do that with in the script via sed or so (not manually)?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the question is but you can do something like that I believe: ```\/home\/teams\/blabla\/blabla.yaml```, escaping the / sign

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU bash and its [Parameter Expansion](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
echo "${CONFIG//\//\\/}"
```

Output:

```
\/home\/teams\/blabla\/blabla.yaml
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407523/escape-a-string-for-a-sed-replace-pattern), in your case it will look like this:

```
CONFIG=$(echo "/home/teams/blabla/blabla.yaml" | sed -e 's/[]\/$*.^[]/\\&/g')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "/home/teams/blabla/blabla.yaml" | sed 's/\//\\\//g'
\/home\/teams\/blabla\/blabla.yaml
```

**explanation**:

backslash is used to set the following letter/symbol as an regular expression or vice versa. double backslash is used when you need a backslash as letter.

Answer (score 0):

Why does that *need* escaping? Is this an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)?

If the issue is that you are trying to use that variable in a substitution regex, then the examples given should work, but you might benefit by removing some of the "leaning toothpick syndrom", which many tools can do just by using a different match delimiter. `sed`, for example:

```
$: sed "s,SOME_PLACEHOLDER_VALUE,$CONFIG," <<< SOME_PLACEHOLDER_VALUE
/home/teams/blabla/blabla.yaml
```

Be very careful about this, though. Commas are perfectly valid characters in a filename, as are almost *anything* but NULLs. Know your data.